# Javascript mouseover event to change form submit button image

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, dom-events

I am attempting to dynamically change the "src" attribute of a form submit button via JavaScript by containing the form element within a link in order to capture the mouseover event.  Here is my code:

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
  paypal_img_mouse_over = new Image(120,120); 
  paypal_img = new Image(120,120); 
  paypal_img_mouse_over.src="Paypal_Button_Mouseover.png"; 
  paypal_img.src="Paypal_Button.png"; 

function Paypal_Mouse_Over()
{
  document.Paypal_Button.src=paypal_img_mouse_over.src;
}
function Paypal_Mouse_Out()
{
  document.Paypal_Button.src=paypal_img.src;
} 
</script>
```

...

And later on, the form element:

...

```
    <a href="#" onMouseOver="Paypal_Mouse_Over()" onMouseOut="Paypal_Mouse_Out()">
        <input type="image" src="Paypal_Button.png" name="Paypal_Button" id="Paypal_Button" value=" Continue ">
    </a>
</form>
```

Should this method be working as rollover effect for my form submit image?

Comment: This can be done in simple CSS, are you limited to using Javascript? If so, you can use the jQuery framework to easily change the attribute of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either use :hover CSS property or jQuery's $.hover() function to achieve this.

Comment: See also [this explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/sel_hover.asp) and [this hover sample](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_hover).

Comment: CSS can change a specific property of a form element?  Could you please link to an example of this?

Comment: I need to update the SRC property of the submit button dynamically - css hover can accomplish this?